# vue v-for rerender a loop in a loop

Tags: vue.js, v-for, vue-reactivity

I am having a re-render issue with my v-for.
having this component as parent

```html
<category
          v-for="category in categories"
          :key="category.id"
          ref="category"
          :category-data="category"
          :audits-data.sync="audits"
          @delete-category="deleteCategory"
          @update-audits="catched"
/>
```

and this one below as child

```html
<audit
            v-for="audit in audits"
            :key="audit.id"
            ref="audit"
            :audit-data="audit"
            @delete-audit="deleteAudit"
          />
```

Problem is, I use props to pass the data from parent to child,
in this case `category-data` has a Object, which is in the next step the data for the `audit` loop

How can I delete one element in audit and force the category key to re-render the himself(category) and the child(audit) by just passing props inside the v-for.

I am using emits, fired up from `audits` to trigger a `getCategories()` function inside `category` component.

problem is, when I delete a audit, the audits wont be reactive and reload because the category is still the same so it wont start a re-render chain for audits.

How can I force a re-render of v-for `category` even when no categories are changed but only `audits` are updated.

Comment: You should add more code. Text description is not enough...

Comment: i am making a codesandbox

Comment: The `key` attribute is the trigger for re-rendering the component. Generate a key which suffices your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I would have emitted a delete event at the child scope and handled the same at the parent scope, thus allowing the main list to get updated. To make an array reflect its changed state either re-assign its value (try map -> filter) or splice it post some transformation. Based on what I could infer from your problem statement this is what I would like to suggest. I have made a small app for the same. Feel free to fork it and hope it helps.

[Example application](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-water-ozd95?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

As stated by @ssc-hrep3, updating a key attribute will trigger a re-rendering of the underlying component. However it seems that your problem is related to a reactivity detection issue, so you should not solve it by forcing a re-rendering.
As you seem to use nested objects and / or arrays, your reactivity issue is likely linked to [Vue change detection caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects).

You should then try something like that:
`Vue.set(this.categories, index, updatedAudits)`

My advice on such complex data-nested use cases would be to first simplify your model (e.g. set category.audits="test string" before trying the full real case), check it is properly reactive, and then add one level of complexity at a time